# How to terminate a http request without sending out response?

Tags: http, go, request

Using go's native http library in a web app, I'm wondering what is the idomatic way to terminate a bad http reqeust without sending back any response.
What I currently do is this:

```
func SomeController(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if IsDodgyRequest(r) {
        return
    }
//rest of the controlloer
}
```

However I'm not sure if it leads to some memory leaks, performance issues or other problems down the road. So appreciate your hits.

Comment: @Flimzy that's not true at all. `400 Bad Request` is an appropriate response in a lot of cases that absolutely should reach the handler, like missing or mistyped parameters, legal but invalid body content (e.g. invalid JSON or invalid XML), etc.

Comment: @Flimzy by `bad` I mean anything undesirable from unauthorized to flooded requests.

Comment: Okay, in that case, you should _not_ "terminate the request". The only time terminating a request is appropriate is if you receive an invalid HTTP request--which won't be passed to your handler.  If you mean  valid HTTP request, that is semantically incorrect, then the only idiomatic response is to return an error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return from the handler without writing anything, the HTTP connection will return with a 200 status code and empty body. You should return an error from such connections, such as `http.StatusBadRequest`. Either case, there will be no leakes because of this.